# how to pass a where statement in a viewbag

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass a where statement in a viewbag to a view. I am trying to pass the equipment status that equals 'In' but it won't work. It wont display the condition.

```
ViewBag.EquipmentID = new SelectList(db.Equipments.Where(o => o .EquipmentStatus== "In"), "EquipmentID", "EquipmentType", hire.EquipmentID);
```

my view to select an equipment is:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EquipmentID, "EquipmentID", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("EquipmentID", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EquipmentID)
            </div>
        </div>
```

My hire model is:

```
  public class Hire
    {
        public int HireID { get; set; }
        public int EquipmentID { get; set; }
        public int PurchaseID { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime ReturnedDate { get; set; }

        public virtual Purchase Purchases { get; set; }
        public virtual Equipment Equipments { get; set; }
    }
```

using the viewmodel method it says in the view that "the name 'model' does not exist in the current context"
this is my view:

```
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EquipmentID, "EquipmentID", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
               @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EquipmentID, model.SelectList)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EquipmentID)
            </div>
        </div>
```

The 'model' in 'model.Equipment' is underlined with the error

this is my controller:

```
   public ActionResult Create(int ID)
        {

           var hire = new Hire();
            Purchase purchase = db.Purchasess.Find(ID);
            ViewHire responseModel = new ViewHire()
            {
                PurchaseID = purchase.PurchaseID,
                EquipmentID = hire.EquipmentID,
                SelectList = new SelectList(db.Equipments.Where(o => o.EquipmentStatus == "In"), "EquipmentID", "EquipmentType", hire.EquipmentID),
            };



            ViewBag.PurchaseID = new SelectList(db.Purchasess, "PurchaseID", "PurchaseID");
            return View(responseModel );
        }
```

Comment: you should use a view model and not a ViewBag. it is best practice to pass everything the view needs in a viewmodel including select lists etc... so everything is strongly typed too and helps prevent runtime errors. furthermore, are you sure you actually get values returned here?

Comment: What is not working? What values are you getting? And how are you generating the dropdownlist in the view?

Comment: I have updated my question. please can you help

Comment: You still have not indicated what is not working, But the first thing you need to do is change it to `ViewBag.EquipmentList = new SelectList(...)` and in the view `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EquipmentID, (SelectList)ViewBag.EquipmentList, String.Empty)` - the `ViewBag` property needs to be a different name than the model property. You can also remove the last parameter from the `SelectList` constructor

Comment: He didn't take on board any of the comments lol.  Just went straight for the dodgy ViewBag implementation xD

Comment: You shouldn't include this kind of logic in your view. It makes your view messy and the code becomes hard to maintain. You will be better off handling this kind of data manipulation/filtration either in your view model or, what's better, in your domain model (business layer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```
ViewBag.Equipments = new SelectList(db.Equipments.Where(o => o .EquipmentStatus== "In"), "EquipmentID", "EquipmentType");
```

And in your view write:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.EquipmentID,(SelectList)ViewBag.Equipments,String.Empty)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the issue is that you are passing your model through the ViewBag and not passing it through to your view using `View()` in your controller.

Therefore, when you use a Html helper like `@Html.DropDownList(model => model.Property)` it won't find the values that you're wanting to pass through.

Your view should have a view model defined in there at the top of the file, then your view knows what type of view model to expect, such as:

```
@model MyViewModel
```

Your view model should be defined as a class within your project, such as:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int EquipmentId { get; set; }
    public SelectList SelectList { get; set; }
}
```

Then within your controller, assign the values to an instance of your class:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    // Code to retrieve hire and db instances...

    var responseModel = new MyViewModel()
    {
        EquipmentId = hire.EquipmentID,
        SelectList = new SelectList(db.Equipments.Where(o => o .EquipmentStatus== "In"), "EquipmentID", "EquipmentType", hire.EquipmentID),
    };

    // Return your view model to the view without using the ViewBag
    return View(responseModel);
}
```

Now that you're passing your model through, your HTML helpers will have access to the values:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EquipmentId, model.SelectList)
```

Comment: If you add this particular bit of code to the question I'll be able to work out why :)

Comment: I have updated my question with using the view model. please help

Comment: Have you defined your model type in the view?

Comment: I can't see it in the code that you've provided... :(